# How to line break a siunitx unit

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx

I made a new command for this unit:

```
\SI{#1(#3)e#2}{\KBE\per\gram\of{FM}}
```

But it is so bulky and it seems that latex can t handle the "normal" linebreak.
So, my new UNIT is sometimes over the normal text width on the right margin

Is there an `siunitx` option to handle this, or any other solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) While the problem is clear enough, at least to me, it's always a good idea to give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. For example, here other people might not work out what is going on with your units.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: no, you cannot break inside units, only at the join between the value and unit (option `allow-number-unit-breaks`). Thus to allow a break within the unit here you would need to write it (or at least part of it) out by hand

```
\SI{#1(#3)e#2}{\KBE}\break\si{\per\gram\of{FM}}
```

Longer answer: When I wrote `siunitx` version two I looked very hard at this. The 'rules' say that breaking units is *bad*, but sometimes it is necessary. However, it was not possible to come up with a way of allowing breaks here while maintaining the other things that `siunitx` does, and in particular not breaking stuff that already worked in version one. Internally, the entire unit is inside a (non-breakable) `\hbox` to let me deal with bold math, and the spacing problem cannot be solved while doing this.

Comment: For the interested: If/when I redo the ideas in `siunitx` for LaTeX3 'proper', this is one thing I'd do differently. That would mean some change in other parts of the 'spec'.

Comment: Thank you, the option "allow-number-unit-breaks" made it. By the way, I made a short example and it worked, but I can t say why. You saved me a lot of time :o)