# Induce line break between number and unit in siunitx in cases latex does not do it autmatically

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx

I have a question related to this one: [How to line break a siunitx unit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70326/how-to-line-break-a-siunitx-unit). In my case I have paragraphs where even with `allow-number-unit-breaks=true` no break happens in some cases (see example below). I can see why Latex has problems with that, as there are so many long units in one paragraph but it is not making me happy.

This is happening a couple of time during a 100 page long thesis, so I am looking for any fix to this that is better than manually inducing linebreaks before printing as I think that is really scary.

Thanks your taking the time, any help appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[
allow-number-unit-breaks=true   
]{siunitx}  

\DeclareSIUnit[]{\tco}{\text{$\textup{t}_{\textup{\ce{CO2}eq.}}$}}
\DeclareSIUnit[]{\teth}{\text{$\textup{t}_{\textup{Eth.}}$}}

\begin{document}

For the initial scenario assumptions, the conventional system yields emissions of \SI{5.00}{\tco\per\teth}, \SI{5.00}{\tco\per\teth} \SI{5.00000}{\tco\per\teth} \SI{5.00}{\tco\per\teth} \SI{5.00}{\tco\per\teth}the second system of \SI{5.00}{\tco\per\teth} and the third of \SI{10.7}{\tco\per\teth}, making the conventional system favourable in terms of emissions. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: If a line break between the number and the second part is allowed, then this is not a “number-unit” combination. Since it happens a couple of times, I'm pretty sure that rewording can help in getting good breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here really is that your units are very long. TeX doesn't want to do the offending line break in your MWE because it would be a bad one (you would get an `Underfull \hbox`). In order to get around this, I you could try to make your units shorter.

- First off, your unit definition is a bit over-complicated. You can just use

  ```
  \DeclareSIUnit{\tco}{{t_{\ce{CO2}eq.}}}
  \DeclareSIUnit{\teth}{{t_{Eth.}}}
  ```

  with identical output.
- If you don't mind the different style, you can use the option `per-mode=symbol`, which makes the unit a bit shorter. In your MWE, this is enough. It might not be in your real document, though.
- An even shorter alternative is `per-mode=fraction`, though this may well be deemed too small or ugly, due to the nested subscript in your unit.
- You could allow the exponent of your unit to be above its subscript (like for regular symbols) by omitting the outer group in the unit:

  ```
  \DeclareSIUnit{\tco}{t_{\ce{CO2}eq.}}
  \DeclareSIUnit{\teth}{t_{Eth.}}
  ```
- You could make the unit symbols themselves a lot shorter, e.g.

  ```
  \DeclareSIUnit{\tco}{{t_c}}
  \DeclareSIUnit{\teth}{{t_e}}
  ```

  You could of course additionally omit the outer group and change `per-mode`, if you prefer.